# Rails Prepared Statement with select_all

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, prepared-statement

As far as I know, it should be possible to do the following in Rails:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT MONTH(created) AS month, YEAR(created) AS year FROM orders WHERE created>=$1 AND created<=$2 GROUP BY month ORDER BY month ASC",nil,[['created',1],['created',2]])
```

but sadly, this is not working at all. whatever format I try to use, the `$1` and `$2` are never replaced with the corresponding values from the bind array.

Is there anything more i should take care of?

Answer (score 7):

You should use `sanitize_sql_array` in your model, like this:

```
r = self.sanitize_sql_array(["SELECT MONTH(created) AS month, YEAR(created) AS year FROM orders WHERE created>=? AND created<=? GROUP BY month ORDER BY month ASC", created1, created2])
self.connection.select_all r
```

This protects you from SQL injections.

Comment: It can also take a hash: `sanitize_sql_array(['... where id = :id and type in (:types)', { id: _, types: _ }])`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using named binds, you would do it like this. This works in Rails 4.2.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(
  "SELECT MONTH(created) AS month, YEAR(created) AS year FROM orders WHERE created>=$1 AND created<=$2 GROUP BY month ORDER BY month ASC",
  nil,
  [[nil,'2016-01-01 12:30'],[nil,'2016-01-01 15:30']]
)
```

Comment: Is it still a thing? I'm getting `TypeError - TypeError:` with nils and `NoMethodError - undefined method `cast_type' for ...` when trying named args. Rails 4.2.10.

Answer (score -14):

I dont understand if you are trying to use variables, but yes it is quite easy to do with variables, you have used them wrongly

Use it like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT MONTH(created) AS month, YEAR(created) AS year FROM orders WHERE created>=#{v1} AND created<=#{v2} GROUP BY month ORDER BY month ASC",nil,[['created',1],['created',2]])
```

Where v1 and v2 are variables.
Let me know if you are trying somthing else

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. actually, I want $1 and $2 to be replaced with [['created',1],['created',2]], just like a common prepared sql statement. but whatever I do, it just doesnt work. In a normal rails model statement like ...where(), it works, but with that base.connection, i cannot figure out, how to do this...

Comment: This is a textbook example of how to create a SQL injection vulnerability in your application -- quote your variables before interpolation, or use bind variables.